# Converting this SQL Query to LINQ

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have a SQL query I wrote in SQL Server but I can't figure out how to do a `GROUP BY` on one of the email columns.

```sql
SELECT tblEmailEvents.dtmEvent,
       tblSentEmails.strEmailSendID,
       tblSentEmails.strSubject,
       COUNT(tblRecipients.lngRecipientNo) AS Recipients, 
       MIN(tblRecipients.strEmailAddress) AS EmailAddress
FROM tblEmailEvents
INNER JOIN tblSentEmails ON tblEmailEvents.strEmailSendID = tblSentEmails.strEmailSendID
INNER JOIN tblRecipients ON tblSentEmails.strEmailSendID = tblRecipients.strEmailSendID
GROUP BY tblSentEmails.strEmailSendID, tblSentEmails.strSubject, tblEmailEvents.dtmEvent
ORDER BY tblEmailEvents.dtmEvent DESC
```

This is what I've came up with far:

```
var query = from mails in this._session.Query<tblSentEmails>()
            join events in this._session.Query<tblEmailEvents>() on mails.strEmailSendID equals events.strEmailSendID
            join recipients in this._session.Query<tblRecipients>() on mails.strEmailSendID equals recipients.strEmailSendID
            where mails.UserId == currentUser.Id
            where (events.dtmEvent >= dtmTimeFrame.AddSeconds(1))
            where events.strType != "Sent"
            orderby events.dtmEvent descending
            //select new
            //       {
            //           Date = events.dtmEvent.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"),
            //           Type = events.strType,
            //           Subject = mails.strSubject,
            //           Recipients = recipients.strEmailAddress
            //       };
            select new
                   {
                       Date = events.dtmEvent.ToString("s"),
                       Type = events.strType,
                       Subject = mails.strSubject,
                       Recipients = recipients.strEmailAddress
                   };
```

I need some help putting the `GROUP BY` as I'm quite lost right now (not a great SQL person here).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please take look. it would be helpful to you.

```
var V = (from State in ST1.State_Master
                group State by State.CountryID into temp
                select new
                {
                   T1 = temp.Key.Value,
                   T2 = temp
                 }).ToList();
```

Let me know if u get resolved ur question

Comment: Wasn't exactly like this but I did manage to get it worked out. Thanks.